# Implement ajax requests in gcloud php application

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine, gcloud

I want make ajax requests in my php application which has been deployed to google cloud. The app.yaml file of my php application looks like below:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /api
  script: api.php
```

I want to make ajax requests with calls to "/api" from jquery, which will be handled by "api.php". But it is not working. How can we specify another script along with index.php. I think api.php is not even getting uploaded. How do we implement ajax requests ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your catch-all catching it before it has a chance.  Rearrange the order:

```
- url: /api
  script: api.php

- url: /.*     ## <- this is a catch-all
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Now I see you've already asked this, and it was properly answered.